# implementing a simple big bang big crunch (BB-BC) in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, mathematical-optimization

i want to implement a simple BB-BC in MATLAB but there is some problem.
here is the code to generate initial population:

```
pop = zeros(N,m);
for j = 1:m
    % formula used to generate random number between a and b
    %   a + (b-a) .* rand(N,1)
   pop(:,j) = const(j,1) + (const(j,2) - const(j,1)) .* rand(N,1);
end
```

`const` is a matrix `(mx2)` which holds constraints for control variables. `m` is number of control variables. random initial population is generated.
here is the code to compute center of mass in each iteration

```
sum = zeros(1,m);
sum_f = 0;
for i = 1:N
    f = fitness(new_pop(i,:));
    %keyboard
    sum = sum + (1 / f) * new_pop(i,:);
    %keyboard
    sum_f = sum_f + 1/f;
    %keyboard
end
CM = sum / sum_f;
```

`new_pop` holds newly generated population at each iteration, and is initialized with `pop`.
`CM` is a `1xm` matrix.
`fitness` is a function to give fitness value for each particle in generation. lower the fitness, better the particle.
here is the code to generate new population in each iteration:

```
for i=1:N
    new_pop(i,:) = CM + rand(1) * alpha1 / (n_itr+1) .* ( const(:,2)' - const(:,1)');
end
```

`alpha1` is `0.9`.

the problem is that i run the code for `100` iterations, but fitness just decreases and becomes negative. it shouldnt happen at all, because all particles are in search space and `CM` should be there too, but it goes way beyond the limits.
for example, if this is the limits (`m=4`):

```
const = [1 10;
     1 9;
     0 5;
     1 4];
```

then running yields this `CM`:

```
57.6955   -2.7598   15.3098   20.8473
```

which is beyond all limits.
i tried limiting `CM` in my code, but then it just goes and sticks at all top boundaries, which in this example give `CM`=

```
10     9     5     4
```

i am confused. there is something wrong in my implementation or i have understood something wrong in BB-BC?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're implementing, but is this like a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)?

Comment: sorry got it. For those not familiar with this optimization algorithm: http://web.itu.edu.tr/~okerol/BBBC.html